# Swift: Safe Thread using NSLock or Concurrent Queue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

What is the best way to do `Safe Thread`?

Using `NSLock`:

```
class Observable<T> {

    typealias Observer = (_ observable: Observable<T>, T) -> Void
    
    private var observers: [Observer]
    private let lock = NSLock()
    private var _value: T

    var value: T {
        get {
            lock.lock()
            let value = _value
            lock.unlock()
            return value
        }
        set {
            lock.lock()
            _value = newValue
            lock.unlock()
        }
    }

    
    init(_ value: T) {
        self._value = value
        observers = []
    }

    func observe(observer: @escaping Observer) {
        self.observers.append((observer))
    }

    private func notifyObservers(_ value: T) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.observers.forEach { [unowned self](observer) in
                observer(self, value)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Using `Queue`:

```
class SecondObservable<T> {

    typealias Observer = (_ observable: SecondObservable<T>, T) -> Void
    
    private var observers: [Observer]
    private let safeQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.observable.value", attributes: .concurrent)
    private var _value: T

    var value: T {
        get {
            var value: T!
            safeQueue.sync { value = _value }
            return value
        }
        set {
            safeQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { self._value = newValue }
        }
    }

    
    init(_ value: T) {
        self._value = value
        observers = []
    }

    func observe(observer: @escaping Observer) {
        self.observers.append((observer))
    }

    private func notifyObservers(_ value: T) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.observers.forEach { [unowned self](observer) in
                observer(self, value)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Or serial `Queue`:

```
class ThirdObservable<T> {

    typealias Observer = (_ observable: ThirdObservable<T>, T) -> Void
    
    private var observers: [Observer]
    private let safeQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.observable.value")
    private var _value: T

    var value: T {
        get {
            var value: T!
            safeQueue.async { value = self._value }
            return value
        }
        set {
            safeQueue.async { self._value = newValue }
        }
    }

    
    init(_ value: T) {
        self._value = value
        observers = []
    }

    func observe(observer: @escaping Observer) {
        self.observers.append((observer))
    }

    private func notifyObservers(_ value: T) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.observers.forEach { [unowned self](observer) in
                observer(self, value)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`NSLock` or a `Queue` with `.concurrent` attribute for the above case, and why?

Comment: Getters with `async` are incorrect. When fetching the value, you have to use `sync`, rather than `async`. E.g., `get { safeQueue.sync { _value } }`. With `async`, you’re not assured that the closure will run before you return the value.

Comment: Also, you never should use `unowned` in conjunction with asynchronous updates. If the object in question is deallocated by the time the asynchronous process finishes, you’ll crash. Use `weak` in conjunction with `async`, not `unowned`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But which of the options is better

Comment: One is not inherently better than the other. For most practical cases, it really doesn't matter. The difference is not generally observable and worrying about it here smacks of premature optimization. That having been said, of these three scenarios, I tend to use locks, which are most performant in my benchmarks. The reader-writer scenario (your second option) is elegant and is potentially more performant than the serial queue (your third option), though in practice, not observably so and at the cost of being less intuitive. But benchmark them and make up your own mind.

Comment: FWIW, you should note that none of these patterns actual guarantee, more generally, thread safety. They only provide thread safe accessors. Sometimes that is sufficient, but often it’s not.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concurrent queue with `barrier` flag is more efficient than using `NSLock` in this case.

Both of them block other operations while a setter is running but the difference is when you call multiple getters concurrently or parallelism.

- `NSLock`: *Only allow 1 getter* running at a time
- Concurrent Queue with `barrier` flag: *Allow multiple getters* running at a time.

Comment: Ok so in this case we prefer the concurrent queue because it allows several setter (in serial) and this is what is needed for the purpose of this Observable object?

Comment: For `observe(observer:)` and `notifyObservers(_:)` methods, there is no difference between using `NSLock` and Concurrent Queue or Serial Queue.

Comment: Do I have to wrap the code in `observe (observe:)` and `notifyObservers (_ :)` with `NSLock` or with the `queue`? And why?

Comment: Actually you can think `observe (observe:)` is a setter (modifying `observers`) and `notifyObservers (_ :)` is a getter (reading `observers`) so they should be wrapped using lock or queue. Unless, calling them concurrently or parallelism will lead to crash same as `_value`.

Comment: You should benchmark this. When I last benchmarked this in massively concurrent pattern, the lock based approach was more efficient. Conventional wisdom used to be that locks were less efficient, but in all of my recent benchmarks, the converse is true.